# Редирект {QUERY_STRING} в нижний регистр

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Всем привет!
Есть самописный сайт, без какого-либо движка/cms.
Eсть ссылки, вида:

```
site.ru/search.php?str=Наименование
site.ru/search.php?str=НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ
```

Стоит задача, сделать редирект таких ссылок в нижний регистр, т.е. перевести все, что есть в {QUERY_STRING} в нижний регистр.

```
site.com/search.php?str=наименование
```

Самое простое решение - RewriteMap, но использовать не получится, так как хостинг обычный и техподдержка в httpd.conf добавлять что-либо отказалась.

**Есть ли какой-либо способ, кроме** использования правил для каждой буквы:

```
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
```

или обработчика на php ([данный вариант почему-то не сработал у меня](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php/))?

```
RewriteCond <отлов uppercase кириллицы>
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основной ответ в продолжении вопроса [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457619/lowercase-query-string-htaccess-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)
Дублирую. Рассматривается ситуация в которой нет возможности использовать RewriteMap.

Для того, чтобы перевести QUERY_STRING, содержащий кириллицу в нижний регистр, необходимо:

1) В .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %D0%([AF].)
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

%D0%([9A].)|(81) - определяет кириллицу в верхрнем регистре, А-Я

2)Содержимое rewrite-strtolower.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    function myUrlEncode($string) {
        $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
        $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
        return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
    }

    if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {     
        $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
        unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
        $params = http_build_query($_GET);
        if(strlen($params)) {         
            $params = '?' . myUrlEncode(mb_strtolower(urldecode($params),"UTF-8"));
        }
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $url . $params, true, 301);
        exit;
    } 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
?>
```

Мы получаем содержимое QUERY_STRING в $params, затем декодируем при помощи urldecode, после чего вызываем mb_strtolower, указав кодировку UTF-8. После, кодируем обратно при помощи функции myUrlEncode.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить в приведенном скрипте strtolower($url) на [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtolower.php)($url)

> В отличие от strtolower(), то что символ является буквой определяется на основании свойств символа Юникода. Таким образом на поведение функции не влияют региональные настройки системы, а также функция может преобразовывать символы, имеющие буквенные особенности, такие как А-умляут (Ä).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Nikita Romannikov, вы бы уточняли, что это для обработчика на php указанного автором в вопросе, а то заминусуют быстрые на руку товарищи вас ;)

Comment: @Visman, это указано в комментарии - "Попробуйте заменить **в приведенном скрипте**"

Comment: @kry4a, я это видел, но минус кто-то уже успел поставить за "php в .htaccess". P.S. Если ответ верен, то отметьте его как решение вопрпоса.