# Lowercase {QUERY_STRING}, .htaccess и кириллица

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

У меня есть ссылки вида:

```
site.ru/script.php?test=ПРИВЕТ
site.ru/script.php?test=Привет
```

Нужно привести к виду:

```
site.ru/script.php?test=привет
```

К сожалению, я не могу использовать `RewriteMap`. Вследствие чего, я использовал обработчик на php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Содержимое rewrite-strtolower.php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    function myUrlEncode($string) {
        $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
        $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
        return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
    }

    if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {     
        $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
        unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
        $params = http_build_query($_GET);
        if(strlen($params)) {         

            $params = '?' . myUrlEncode(mb_strtolower(urldecode($params),"UTF-8"));
            echo $params;
        }
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $url . $params, true, 301);
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

После всех преобразований я получаю удовлетворяющий меня QUERY_STRING в нижнем регистре, но попадаю с ним опять под

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [A-Z]
```

В следствие чего - циклическое перенаправление...

**Как быть? Как заставить .htaccess в RewriteCond определять кириллицу?**

Если не для редиректа на lowercase, то хотя для редиректа в виде
`site.ru/script.php?test=Привет` на транслит `site.ru/script/privet`

Comment: А зачем вам параметр в адресной строке в нижнем регистре? Я вот про это `site.ru/script.php?test=ПРИВЕТ -> site.ru/script.php?test=привет`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рецепт №1 Не делайте редиректа если в скрипт попадает строка в нижнем регистре, обрабатывайте такие запросы при помощи PHP.

Рецепт №2 Ловите кириллицу в QS при помощи вот такой конструкции `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %[89A-F].`

%{QUERY_STRING} - обрабатывается в закодированном виде. Все, что опасно для запроса, кодируется в виде %xx, где xx - шестнадцатеричный код символа. См. [Percent-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) (по-английски)

Чтобы "поймать" верхний регистр русской кириллицы в UTF-8 нужна такая проверка

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %D0%([9A].)|(81)
```

`%D0%90` - `%D0%AF` это закодированные символы `А` - `Я`, `%D0%81` - `Ё` (всё это в кодировке UTF-8)

Обратите внимание, что в `RewriteRule` URL декодируется, то есть там вы будете иметь дело непосредственно с кириллицей, причем в той кодировке, в которой ее вводили на странице или в адресной строке.

**Дополнено**

Чуть не забыл пояснить почему `%[8-f]`. На самом деле я ошибся. Конечно должно быть `%[89A-F].` Хотя будет работать и неправильный вариант, если только запрос специально не будет сформирован так, чтобы это сработало тогда, когда не должно. Таким выражением мы "ловим" все символы с кодом больше 0x7f. Символы кириллицы во всех кодовых таблицах будут иметь такие символы.

Comment: `[8-f]` что это, почему работает?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Еще дополнил ответ

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо Вам! Рецепт №2 Сработал!