# Почему функция не преобразует строку в нижний регистр

Tags: php

> $a = 'ВЫАЫАЫПЫВП'; echo strtolower( $a );

Comment: Используйте функцию `mb_strtolower()`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448681/285292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что кириллица. Используйте `mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8')`